# Disallow entering value in multiple row block Oracle Forms

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracleforms

My table looks like this:

```
+-------------------+
|Name               |
+-------------------+
|Name1              |
|Name2              |
|Name3              |
|Name4              |
|Name1Jr            |
|Name2Jr            |
|Name3Jr            |
|Name4Jr            |
+-------------------+
```

My multirow block looks like:

[image]

And what I wanted is to disallow entering a Name ending with Jr if the name doesn't exists in the block. Something like this:

If I enter values Name1 and Name2:

[image]

Then it will allow me to enter Name1Jr and Name2Jr but not the names with Jr that are in the LOV but not yet in the block:

[image]

**Note:** I am using List of Values for this column. Thanks!

Comment: First, not clear why your LOV should have jr. values if you do not want them to inserts. Second, you can add when-validate-item trigger to check if values inserted is jr. or not. If jr. - if :block.item name like '%...jr%.' then raise form trigger failure with some message. If you need to validate on block level then add when-validate-block (I forgot the exact name of the trigger, sorry) to the block level. Same to the record level - use the record level trigger. For help with 'like %' operator look at the COPY command in Forms help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two options.

**The first one** relies on the table contents. As you use List of Values (LOV), it might look like this (suppose that table name is TEST, represented by a CTE): you'd `UNION` current names with *fabricated* "name**Jr**" values (`DECODE` is here to avoid "Name3JrJr" situation):

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'Name1'   from dual union
  3     select 'Name3'   from dual union
  4     select 'Name3Jr' from dual
  5    )
  6  select col from test
  7  union
  8  select col || decode(substr(col, -2), 'Jr', null, 'Jr') from test
  9  order by col;

COL
---------
Name1
Name1Jr
Name3
Name3Jr

SQL>
```

Form item's "Validate from List" property should be set to "Yes", so that Forms rejects values that don't exist in the LOV.

But, what if you enter name that doesn't exist in a table? For example, "Name2"? In `WHEN-VALIDATE-ITEM` trigger use `SET_ITEM_PROPERTY` and modify `VALIDATE_FROM_LIST` property to `PROPERTY_FALSE`. Set it back to `TRUE` in `WHEN-CREATE-RECORD` trigger.

Furthermore, you'll have to accept newly added "Name2" value and display it in LOV. How? `POST` changes you've made (don't `COMMIT`, just `POST`). Where? As it is a restricted procedure, try `KEY-NEXT-ITEM` and `WHEN-NEW-RECORD-INSTANCE` triggers.

**The second option** would create LOV dynamically and its values would be values currently displayed in the block. You'd use `CREATE_GROUP` built-in, along with `ADD_GROUP_ROW` which would add block values into the Record Group (and it is a source for a LOV). `WHEN-NEW-RECORD-INSTANCE` might be your choice as it allows restricted procedures, and you should "scroll" through the block in a loop, using `NEXT_RECORD` (wich *is* restricted). Read about CREATE_GROUP in Forms Help; it contains an example of how to use it. Also, follow links to other examples, if necessary.

Comment: Sorry sir @Littlefoot. I think that my question earlier is not clear. I edited some. Please reread it. Thank you again.

Comment: Apply that condition to LOV's Record Group query.

Comment: Thank you very much sir!